# More than one GPU in Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I was trying to run a Python code from GitHub on Google Colab, I need 2 GPUs to run the code, I installed Pytorch with this command: `!conda install pytorch=0.4.1 cuda90 -c pytorch`, When I try to run code, I get an error about cuda device:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 188, in <module>
    encoder.cuda(encoder_gpus[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 258, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 185, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 185, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 191, in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 258, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
RuntimeError: CUDA error (10): invalid device ordinal
```

Is that error because of the number of GPUs to run the code? how many GPUs are available in Google Colab?
How can we access more than one GPU in Google Colab?( is it possible to access more Gpus with "Colab Pro")

Comment: run `!nvidia-smi` in colab to get info about available gpus

Comment: @AlexLarionov I did, I only have one GPU, I want to know how can I have more than one GPU in Colab?

Comment: Can you narrow the question area, please? Do you have a problem with the snippet you shared or you want to know how many GPUs are available in colab?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have 1 GPU in Colab.